# Limit download speed per user

Tags: windows-server-2012

is it possible to limit the download/upload speed per user ?
Windows Server 2012

i mean to limit what the user can download and upload not in iis but in the server it self; as like for a RDP user or just a windows user

example :
Administrator : Unlimited/Unlimited
User1 : 5mbps/2mbps
User2 : 10mbps/2mbps

Comment: Are you trying to configure this at a domain controller? You need to provide more information about your environment.

Comment: @bwDraco no it's not related to iis, i mean to limit what a user can download and upload not in iis but in the server it self; as like for a RDP user or just a windows user

Comment: I'm finding this rather hard to understand. Are you trying to throttle the Internet connection speed on the server itself or on domain-joined machines?

Comment: @bwDraco on the server itself, but every user should have a custom limit

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Server 2012 you can limit bandwidth trough QoS mechanism, however there's no direct way to do it per user.

If you can ensure a specific user will always have the same IP(s) (trough fixed IP or dhcp reservation, provide a user always use the same machine), then you can define QoS policy per IP.

However this doesn't scale well with the number of users.